# Jquery events is not working in my template html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, templates

I am very confused on what is an issue with my testing project. It is a free template that I got from the site that offering free templates. I downloaded it and I tried to mix it with Angularjs but I cant make work the menu button that is displaying on/off when clicked. I tried several solutions from the net that I think can solve the problem but no luck.

**template HTML**

```
<div class="menu">                                              
  <a href="" class="right_bt" id="activator"><img src="img/landing/menu.png" alt=""/></a>
    <div class="box" id="box">
      <div class="box_content">
        <div class="menu_box_list">
          <ul>
            <li class="active act"><a class="hvr-underline-from-center scroll" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="hvr-underline-from-center scroll">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services" class="hvr-underline-from-center scroll">Services</a></li>

 <!-- some other codes -->

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('.menu').on('click', '#activator', function() {
      console.log("click");
   });
   var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
   $(function() {
      $('#activator').click(function(){
        $('#box').animate({'top':'0px'},500);
      });

      $('#boxclose').click(function(){
        $('#box').animate({'top':'-700px'},500);
      });
   });
   $(document).ready(function(){
     //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
     $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

     //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
     $(".trigger").click(function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
       return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
     });
  });
</script>
```

The `script` is on the inside of `template html`, and this `template html` is called when specific `state` is active using `ui-router`. .

Comment: you cant use angular and jquery just like that, you need to rewrite the jquery inside a directive.

Comment: So what I am currently doing is impossible. Is the output is the same when I use directives and customize those jquery codes?

Comment: no its not impossible, I will guide you on how to do this. If you could provide a JSFiddle I can give you a great working example.

Comment: Okay thanks Ill try tomorrow its already 3am in my location. I'll need to sleep. Thanks.